# Zend Framework Custom Routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I need to create some custom routes in my ZF v.1.12:

```
protected function _initRouter() {
    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
    $this->bootstrap('locale');

    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance ();
    $router = $front->getRouter ();

    $router->addRoute ( 'fastproduct', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex ( '(.+)\.html', array ('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'get' ), array (1 => 'q' ), '%s.html' ) );
    $router->addRoute ( 'products', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex ( 'products/(.+)\.html', array ('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'get' ), array (1 => 'q' ), 'products/%s.html' ) );
    $router->addRoute ( 'categories', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex ( 'categories/(.+)\.html', array ('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'list' ), array (1 => 'q' ), 'categories/%s.html' ) );
    $router->addRoute ( 'cms', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex ( 'cms/(.+)\.html', array ('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'cms', 'action' => 'page' ), array (1 => 'url' ), 'cms/%s.html' ) );
    $router->addRoute ( 'wiki', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex ( 'wiki/(.+)\.html', array ('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'wiki', 'action' => 'help' ), array (1 => 'uri' ), 'wiki/%s.html' ) );
    $router->addRoute ( 'tlds', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex ( 'tlds/(.+)\.html', array ('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'tlds', 'action' => 'index' ), array (1 => 'uri' ), 'tlds/%s.html' ) );

    return $router;
}
```

Now If I call these links, works as well:

```
# http://www.mydomain.com/productname.html  
# http://www.mydomain.com/products/productname.html
# http://www.mydomain.com/categories/hosting.html
# http://www.mydomain.com/cms/mypage.html
# http://www.mydomain.com/wiki/myhelp.html
# http://www.mydomain.com/tlds/com.html
# http://www.mydomain.com/admin/
```

but **how have I to prepend the language to all these following links?**

```
# http://www.mydomain.com/it/productname.html   
# http://www.mydomain.com/it/products/productname.html
# http://www.mydomain.com/it/categories/hosting.html
# http://www.mydomain.com/it/cms/mypage.html
# http://www.mydomain.com/it/wiki/myhelp.html
# http://www.mydomain.com/it/tlds/com.html
# http://www.mydomain.com/it/admin
```

thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Your default route has optional parameters, so `route_4`, `route_3` and `route_2` are unnecessary - get rid of those. You still need the last one, but you are not using route chaining correctly. Change that one to:

```
$routeLang = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('([a-z]{2})', array('module' => 'default', 'lang' => 'en', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'), array (1 => 'lang' ), '%s' );
$router->addRoute('route_1', $routeLang);
```

You might also want to use more descriptive route names for routes you add.

If it still doesn't work, please update your question to include your updated route config and provide info on how you are checking the matched route params.

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for the help. I have update the code and it works as well. I have updated the question as you told me. Thanks again

Comment: `$router->addRoute('route_1', $defaultRoute);` is incorrect - you should be passing `$routeLang` there (see my answer). The other routes  you have commented out look ok - if you uncomment those, what works and what doesn't?

Comment: My fault! Wrong paste of the code! 
If I execute the "WIKI" with the http://www.mydomain.com/wiki the route consider it as module and not as controller.

Comment: Hi Tim, any clue or hint?